# Fatal error: "No Target Architecture" in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-c++, compiler-errors

When I try to compile my c++ project using Visual Studio 2010 in either Win32 or x64 mode I get the following error:

`>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winnt.h(135): fatal error C1189: #error :  "No Target Architecture"`

My preprocessor definitions say WIN32;_DEBUG;_CONSOLE;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)

What is causing this error and how do I fix it?

```
// winnt.h: lines 127-136, MSVS says this is an inactive preprocessor block
#if defined(_WIN64)

#if defined(_AMD64_)
#define PROBE_ALIGNMENT( _s ) TYPE_ALIGNMENT( DWORD )
#elif defined(_IA64_)
#define PROBE_ALIGNMENT( _s ) (TYPE_ALIGNMENT( _s ) > TYPE_ALIGNMENT( DWORD ) ? \
                              TYPE_ALIGNMENT( _s ) : TYPE_ALIGNMENT( DWORD ))
#else
#error "No Target Architecture"
#endif
```

Update: I created a new msvs project and copied my code to it. I no longer have `error : "No Target Architecture"`, but now I have a bunch of compile errors involving winnt.h and winbase.h and no compile errors involving any of my files. Is it possible these files are corrupted? Do I need to reinstall MSVS 2010?

Update 2: So I narrowed down my problem and found that it is `#include <WinDef.h>` that is causing all of my compile errors with winnt.h but I still don't know how to fix it.

Comment: How do I set the target architecture for my project?

Comment: A vanilla project doesn't fail this way. What have you changed from a vanilla project? What is at line 135 of winnt.h? Have you even looked at that line of the header file. The error message is giving you some help.

Comment: you should be able to work it out from here; probably need to go back before line 127 though to get the full picture. It would seem clear that Edwin was correct.

Comment: Try a new msvs project (dummy) and copy-drag your sources into it. Try to compile it and if it does ,compare it with your original project. BTW don't copy the stdafx.*

Comment: Does sound bad. But before you do a re-install ,you first could try it with a new solution and if that doesn't work you can manualy re-install project=templates (google it).

Answer (score 228, accepted):

Use `#include <windows.h>` instead of `#include <windef.h>`.

From the [`windows.h`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows.h) wikipedia page:

> There are a number of child header files that are automatically included with `windows.h`. Many of these files cannot simply be included by themselves (they are not *self-contained*), because of dependencies.

`windef.h` is one of the files automatically included with `windows.h`.

Comment: I did think of that ,but I couldn't imaging that you didn't include windows.h.

Comment: windows.h defines alkinds of other defines based on compiler-switches and includes many WINAPI-headers ,some of which depending on things defned by windows.h.

Comment: congratulations, you have fixed your problem **and** you have enough rep to vote up!

Comment: Neither windows.h not windowsx.h (I assume them to be the same thing but have tried both anyway) help with that `#error Hey man you gotta choose a target.`. What else could fix that?

Comment: Heads up: seems including Xinput.h before Windows.h causes this too.

Comment: If I include Windows.h I get told that I cannot include it twice. Why doesn't it just ignore the second inclusion?

Comment: In my case it was <windows.h> instead of <winnt.h>

Comment: All of these #includes xyz errors are one of include ordering...ie if #include <xinput.h> is followed by #include <windows.h> then the error "no target architecture" pops up. Because xinput.h depends on windows.h, solution.... *swap the order* ie include <windows.h> ... #include <xinput.h>.  moral of the story #include <windows.h> BEFORE other windows includes.

Answer (score 44):

Another cause of this can be including a header that depends on `windows.h`, before including `windows.h`.

In my case I included `xinput.h` before `windows.h` and got this error.  Swapping the order solved the problem.

Comment: Exactly my solution! Thanks for saving me hours of frustration.

Answer (score 16):

Solve it by placing the following include files and definition first:

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN      // Exclude rarely-used stuff from Windows headers

#include <windows.h>
```

Comment: This fixed both my x86 and x64 builds. I needed to add these lines before `#include <WinUser.h>`.

Answer (score 12):

If you are using Resharper make sure it does not add the wrong header for you, very common cases with ReSharper are:

- `#include <consoleapi2.h`
- `#include <apiquery2.h>`
- `#include <fileapi.h>`

**UPDATE**:
Another suggestion is to check if you are including a "partial Windows.h", what I mean is that if you include for example winbase.h or minwindef.h you may end up with that error, add "the big" Windows.h instead. There are also some less obvious cases that I went through, the most notable was when I only included synchapi.h, the docs clearly state that is the header to be included for some functions like AcquireSRWLockShared but it triggered the No target architecture, the fix was to remove the synchapi.h and include "the big" Windows.h.

The Windows.h is huge, it defines macros(many of them remove the No target arch error) and includes many other headers. **In summary**, always check if you are including some header that **could be replaced by Windows.h** because it is not unusual to include a header that relies on some constants that are defined by Windows.h, so if you fail to include this header your compilation may fail.

Comment: Thank you. I include `windows.h` to replace `WinBase.h` and `fileapi.h`.

Answer (score 6):

windows 10x64 pro build 19044.1586

My case was in order of .h files

Like this is dosen't work

```
#include <processthreadsapi.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
```

But works like this

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <processthreadsapi.h>
```

Answer (score 5):

_WIN32 identifier is not defined.

use `#include <SDKDDKVer.h>`

MSVS generated projects wrap this include by generating a local `"targetver.h"`which is included by `"stdafx.h"` that is comiled into a precompiled-header through `"stdafx.cpp"`.

EDIT : do you have a /D "WIN32" on your commandline ?

Comment: Should it be `_WIN32` rather than `WIN32`? It's not my area of expertise, but given that the header is looking for `_WIN64`, '_AMD64_` etc. it would seem plausible.

Comment: @David Heffernan : at the commandline it says WIN32 (no _) even for x84. Don't know the rationale of it (but who does understand MS)

Comment: @Edwin x84? Is that George Orwell's computer?

Comment: @David Heffernan: yes ,big brother is watching me ! (obviously x64 i meant)

Comment: In my case _WIN32 was defined and was the culprit. I was building for x64. Your answer put me on track. Good job!

Answer (score 4):

It would seem that `_AMD64_` is not defined, since I can't imagine you are compiling for Itanium (`_IA64_`).

Comment: _AMD64_ will be defined under some conditions:#if !defined(_68K_) && !defined(_MPPC_) && !defined(_X86_) && !defined(_IA64_) && !defined(_AMD64_) && defined(_M_AMD64)

Comment: @Edwin If `_AMD64_` or `_IA64_` was defined, then he wouldn't be getting the error. That's what the header file says.

Comment: philipvr has updated his post. He has other (more) problems. He's thinking re-install MSVS.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem. In my case, I had accidentally included `winuser.h` before `windows.h` (actually, a buggy IDE extension had added it). Removing the `winuser.h` solved the problem.

Comment: For me ReSharper added `consoleapi2.h`

Answer (score 4):

At the beginning of the file you are compiling, before any `include`, try to put ONE of these lines

```
#define _X86_
#define _AMD64_
#define _ARM_
```

Choose the appropriate, only one, depending on your architecture.

Answer (score 2):

Besides causes described already, I received this error because I'd include:

```
#include <fileapi.h>
```

Apparently it was not needed (despite of CreateDirectoryW call). After commenting out, compiler was happy. Very strange.

Comment: I have exactly the same situation.

Comment: _Very strange._ No - not strange if you consider the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4845893/7478597).

Answer (score 1):

Another reason for the error (amongst many others that cropped up when changing the target build of a Win32 project to X64) was not having the C++ 64 bit compilers installed as noted at the top of [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yb4317s(v=vs.100).aspx). 
Further to philipvr's comment on child headers, (in my case) an explicit include of *winnt.h* being [unnecessary](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8999e604-d95f-4e00-b171-6baa31e4cde5/what-if-i-include-winnth-directly?forum=vcgeneral) when *windows.h* was being used.

Comment: Another visit to this page arose when an old project happened to have ` #include <synchapi.h>` in a CriticalSection header.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid explicitly including a specific Windows SDK header, then something like this should work:

```
#if defined(__amd64__) || defined(__amd64) || defined(__x86_64__) || defined(__x86_64) || defined(_M_X64) || defined(_M_AMD64)
#define _AMD64_
#elif defined(i386) || defined(__i386) || defined(__i386__) || defined(__i386__) || defined(_M_IX86)
#define _X86_
#elif defined(__arm__) || defined(_M_ARM) || defined(_M_ARMT)
#define _ARM_
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are building 32bit then make sure you don't have _WIN64 defined for your project.

Answer (score 0):

for me I was using glfw and imgui, and I included this header file by mistake:

```
#include <stringapiset.h>
```

I just removed it and this error no longer

Answer (score 0):

Like before Анатолий Иванов give answer:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <processthreadsapi.h>
```

but in my case was to remember position of **windows.h** before "**iostream**".