# Include winnt.h in my project

Tags: c++, windows

I am doing a small personal project involving printing out info about a PE file.
I have read that most of the pe structure is already defined in winnt.h header.

Upon including the winnt.h, and compiling the project i get the following error:

```
#error :  "No Target Architecture"
```

I tried putting a define *x86*, it might have fixed the architecture problem, but there are even more compilation problems.

For example:

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.0\include\um\winnt.h(363): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'WCHAR'
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.0\include\um\winnt.h(363): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.0\include\um\winnt.h(367): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.0\include\um\winnt.h(367): error C2040: 'PWSTR' : 'CONST' differs in levels of indirection from 'WCHAR *'
```

Comment: _'but there are even more compilation problems'_ Which ones in particular?

Comment: edited to include some other problems - there are over 230

Comment: What compiler are you using - Visual C++ or something else? If you're using a Microsoft compiler then it should already set up all of the architecture etc. defines it's expecting, unless you're doing something strange!

Comment: I'm using the VS2012 compiler, and the only thing that I am doing is including the wint.h at the top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> check Compiler->Enable Microsoft extensions in Project options or use -Ze flag if you're compiling from the command line.

Comment: i am using VS2012, and I can't find this menu. On MSDN I found the Language->Disable Language Extensions which seems does the same job, I had it set to No. Setting it to Yes(/Za), did not solve the problem though.

Comment: Try this one....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845198/fatal-error-no-target-architecture-in-visual-studio-2010

Comment: Found that similar to yours

Comment: Including Windows.h fixed the issue.