# Code generation of linked blocks in Simulink

Tags: simulink, matlab-compiler

I am trying to generate code of my Simulink Model. The model contains linked blocks and Level 2 S-functions.
I am getting the following error when I press the Build Model Button

```
MyFluidProp_mod6.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "double __cdecl pneu_fluids_PureGasProps_cp(double,class FluidProps &)" (?pneu_fluids_PureGasProps_cp@@YANNAEAVFluidProps@@@Z) referenced in function "double __cdecl cp_Fcn(double,class FluidProps &)" (?cp_Fcn@@YANNAEAVFluidProps@@@Z)
```

Update:
After tracking all required source files, and copying them to the current folder, I end up with the actual error:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\\include\winnt.h(135) : fatal error C1189: #error :  "No Target Architecture"  
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\amd64\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2' 
Stop.
```

From previous [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845198/fatal-error-no-target-architecture-in-visual-studio-2010), it appears that `winnt.h` has to be replaced by `windef.h`. But since it used internally (not by any of my source codes), I can't change it.

This is most probably to a missing link to one of the used libraries. But since I cannot supply any additional commands to the Build Button, I cannot specify the link. I also must admit that I didn't understand exactly the error message meaning.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your most likely not telling the compiler where to look for the library containing the function in question.  This is done on the Configuration Parameters -> Code Generation -> Custom Code tab.  If you right click on the words "Include Directories:" then you can bring up the help, explaining what to put into where.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I never paid attention to these options. But it seems that the code generation is working properly, but instead the build process is generating the above error. Do you have an idea how to debugg the above error, so I know what files are missing?