# Visual Studio doesn't recognize Windows' data types even including its header

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2013

I'm writing a Timer class in VS2013 using some Windows features but Visual Studio doesn't recognize them even including windows.h header.

Win32Timer.h

```
#pragma once

#include "Timer.h"
    
    #ifndef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
    #   define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
    #endif
    #if !defined(NOMINMAX) && defined(_MSC_VER)
    #   define NOMINMAX
    #endif
    #include <windows.h>
    
    class Win32Timer : public Timer {
        public:
            Win32Timer();
            ~Win32Timer();
    
            void reset() override;
            ulong getMilliseconds() override;
            ulong getMillisecondsCPU() override;
            ulong getMicroseconds() override;
            ulong getMicrosecondsCPU() override;
            
        protected:
            ulong getTime() override;
            
        private:
            clock_t m_StartClock;
    
            DWORD m_StartTick;
            LONGLONG m_LastTime;
            LARGE_INTEGER m_StartTime;
            LARGE_INTEGER m_Frequency;
    
    };
```

Timer.h (Prerequisites.h is just a bunch of forward declarations and STL headers)

```
#pragma once

#include "Prerequisites.h"

class Timer {
    public:
        Timer();
        ~Timer();

        virtual void reset() = 0;
        virtual ulong getMilliseconds() = 0;
        virtual ulong getMillisecondsCPU() = 0;
        virtual ulong getMicroseconds() = 0;
        virtual ulong getMicrosecondsCPU() = 0;

    protected:
        virtual ulong getTime();
};
```

When I try to compile I get the following errors for each member variable that uses the windows' data types.

> 1>c:\users\jean\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\drac\drac\win32timer.h(33): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'm_LastTime'
>
> 1>c:\users\jean\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\drac\drac\win32timer.h(33): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

If I click to go to definition, VS takes me to the right place where the data type is defined but fails to recognize it in compile time. What could the problem be?

If I include `<winnt.h>` instead of `<windows.h>` the types are recognized but I get a `fatal error C1189: #error :  "No Target Architecture"`.

Comment: What happens if you include `WinNT.h`?

Comment: Obviously Visual Studio has no problem with SDK headers otherwise people would have noticed decades ago. It's far more likely that there is a syntax error in the header or whatever is in "Timer.h". What is in Timer.h? Are you missing any important headers? What happened to `stdafx.h`? If your project doesn't use precompiled headers, are you missing some necessary headers perhaps?

Comment: Error  error C2146 occurs when what's before the identifier isn't known to the compiler. In your case that means the compiler hasn't seen  DWORD yet. See this example [Compiler Error C2146](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9xbcaa9t.aspx)

Comment: @NathanOliver It recognizes the types but I get a `fatal error C1189: #error :  "No Target Architecture"`. @Panagiotis I edited the post with Timer.h source code, it only include `Prerequisites.h` which is a bunch of forwards declarations and STL headers. `stdafx.h` is in my precompiled headers configuration. @M010 I know that the identifier isn't known to the compiler, the problem is that since I'm including `windows.h`, I expected it to be known.

Comment: Preprocess to file and check if the intended file has been included.

Comment: Maybe, then, you should set a target architecture?  See, e.g., [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4845261/751579).  BTW, the information you added in the comment would be useful in the question itself ... pls update the question (comments are ephemeral).

Comment: @davidbak I checked the answear but didn't find it very clear on how to set a target architecture. I tried including `<SDKDDKVer.h>` before including `<winnt.h>` but there were no differences.