# "No Target Architecture" compilation error in Visual Studio using CMake

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, cmake

I'm trying to compile my `C++` `CMake` project in [`Visual Studio`](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com). However, I'm getting the following error message:

```
#error:  "No Target Architecture"   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CMakeLists.txt   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um\winnt.h  154
```

I checked my code and I'm never including `winnt.h` but I'm including `windows.h` [so this rules out the solution of never including `winnt.h`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4845893/3764804).

This is the `winnt.h` code snippet where it throws the error:

```
//
// TODO: WOWXX - Unblock ARM. Make all alignment checks DWORD for now.
//

#define PROBE_ALIGNMENT( _s ) TYPE_ALIGNMENT( DWORD )
#elif !defined(RC_INVOKED)
#error "No Target Architecture"
#endif
```

I've previously successfully compiled this project using [`MinGW`](https://nuwen.net/mingw.html) and `WSL` (`Windows Subsystem for Linux`) outside of `Visual Studio`. How do I tell `Visual Studio` that my architecture is `64-bit` and `amd64` (?). What is necessary in addition to make it compile? The run configuration is set to `x64-Debug`. Including `stdafx.h` is not possible since the header file is not found. I'm also using [`Boost`](https://www.boost.org) but that is resolved properly by adding the following line to my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set(BOOST_ROOT "C:/local/boost_1_69_0_b1_rc3")
```

Comment: What's your current CMake command? Are you using `cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" ..` ?

Comment: @Chris: I use the `Visual Studio` build function. Using diagnostic output, I got the following build command: `"C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\CMAKE\CMake\bin\CMake.exe" --build "C:\Users\User\CMakeBuilds\9da55f70-6c9e-9f39-9d9d-49fcd309f582\build\x64-Debug" --target MyProject --config Debug  --  "-v"`

Comment: So yeah, you're still using the `cmake` command I mentioned, it seems like your output is not setting the generator `-G "Visual Studio 15 2017"` to `win64`. I'm not familiar with what the `Visual Studio` build function is though. Do you see any settings that allow you to switch the Solution Platform to 64 bit?

Comment: ``--target MyProject`` seems a little weird, just to be sure, you did define a specific target called "MyProject", right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the error message mentioned a file of mine (e.g. `file_operations.h`) [I decided to define the architecture inside it using the following macro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4845618/3764804):

```
#define _AMD64_ 1
```

This fixed the problem but I believe that a "better" solution exists by configuring the `CMakeLists.txt` or `Visual Studio`.

Answer (score 2):

I think this should be fixed by `-DCMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM=x64`

Answer (score 0):

It is not specified if the error happens when the project is being configured or when the project has been configured and you are trying to build.

It could be an issue with your Visual Studio installation as it seems like you are not using cmake at the command line but using the cmake built into Visual Studio.

In both cases cmake will run to verify that a valid program can be built.

In Visual Studio create a new CMake project and it will create a generic c++ project with a CMakeLists.txt file.  When you build this project it will run through the compiler detection phase, project configuration, and build.  On my system this defaults for x86-Debug switch this to x64-Debug and it will go through the process again for x64 architecture.

Personally I think that the bundled CMake interface is very confusing and I don't use it.  It is also using an older CMake and Ninja tools.

If this all works then it is something else that is going wrong and you need to include the full error message.  The full error message will show the chain of include files and may pinpoint if you are using the wrong windows header file.