# Visual Studio Professional 2013, Update 5, "No Target Architecture"

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a CPP project in Visual Studio, I'm getting the following message when I try to build the solution:

```
    1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.1\include\um\winnt.h(147): fatal error C1189: #error :  "No Target Architecture"
```

The contents of stdafx.h:

```
    #pragma once

    #include "targetver.h"

    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <tchar.h>
    #include <ctime>
    #include <time.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <profileapi.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/stat.h>
    #include <Windows.h>
```

What's missing?

Comment: I suggest you could refer to the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845198/fatal-error-no-target-architecture-in-visual-studio.

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT, sorry, I saw and read that before I posted my question, it doesn't help.

Comment: I suspect you'll need to remove `#include <tchar.h>` (you shouldn't be using `TCHAR` anyway, it's been completely obsolete for 18 years now). Also ensure that none of the other include files (such as `targetver.h`) have any `#include <windows.h>` lines.

Comment: I think the problem is `profileapi.h` because it's a Windows header which means it must be included **after** `#include <windows.h>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I found that removing the headers:

```
    profileapi.h
    sys/types.h
```

Resolved the issue and the project now builds without warning or error.

Thank you Dai, the better solution:

```
    #include "targetver.h"
    #include <Windows.h>

    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <tchar.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <chrono>
    #include <ctime>
    #include <time.h>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <profileapi.h>
    #include <sys/stat.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
```

Comment: You can still have those headers in your `stdafx.h` file, but you just need to ensure they're located **below** the `#include <windows.h>` line.