# How to interact with the Win32 API in C++ without an IDE?

Tags: c++, winapi, dependencies, ide, mingw

I have a small project in mind that requires the usage of the Win32 API in C++.

I lack some knowledge concerning the building steps of such an app, so I would like to do it without using Visual Studio, to teach myself how things are working under the hood.

To do so, I got VS Code, MinGW, Make for Windows, and the Win32 API.

After some time figuring out how MinGW and the Make tool work, I'm trying to get my head around libraries and dependencies.

Doing so, I want to compile this truly simple code:

```cpp
/*
header file coming from the win32 api,
 giving access to the Windows Wallpaper, which is what I want to mess with
*/
#include "ShObjIdl_core.h"

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Within my Makefile, I include the two folders where the win32's header files I want are stored:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.20348.0`
`\um`
`\Shared`

The linkage seems successful, but here comes the issue: the compiler is throwing at me a ton of different errors coming from a lot of different files.

Here's a few examples:

```
- error: #error "No Target Architecture"`
- warning: ignoring '#pragma warning ' [-Wunknown-pragmas]
   #pragma warning(disable:4214) // bit field types other than int
- error: cast from 'const void*' to 'long unsigned int' loses precision [-fpermissive]
   return((void *) (ULONG_PTR) (unsigned long) p);
- error: 'PCONTEXT' was not declared in this scope;
```

I've seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845198/) that I should `#include "windows.h"` instead of my specific file, but this doesn't solve the issue, I still get a bunch of errors.

I feel I'm missing an important bit about working with an API, or with dependencies in general, but I just can't find anything on the web to help me understand how this is supposed to work.

Comment: One way of solving your problem would be to go ahead and use Visual Studio, compile a sample program, enable some level of diagnostic build output, and see exactly what parameters are passed by Visual Studio to the compiler and the linker.

Comment: Also, we cannot stress enough that Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code are two **totally** different products. When you search for solutions for one of them, it will generally **not** work at all with the other one. [What are the differences between Visual Studio Code and Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30527522/17398063)

Comment: So your linked solution has 2 major problems - it is from 2011, and it is not for MinGW and VSCode.

Comment: With MinGW you're supposed to use the Windows headers that come with it, *not* the ones from the Windows SDK (in \\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits). Most of these headers (rewritten for MinGW) are outdated but can still work for coding simple stuff that doesn't require on-the-edge or recent Windows APIs.

Comment: You can't avoid `windows.h` (any version of it) if you want to use the Win32 API in any *reasonable* manner. It is core to the whole API, as it defines a lot of base things that the rest of the API uses. I mean, you *could* redefine everything manually, but why bother? The hard work has already been done for you.

Comment: I highly recommend against using the Windows API.  Instead use a GUI framework, like wxWidgets or Qt.  These frameworks hide the Windows API so you can focus on the widgets, like windows or button.  Many also have support for other common tasks (like XML file support).  Unless you have specific reason for accessing the Windows API, don't.

Comment: Have you tried looking into cmake? Its got a windows download and vs code extensions. Also you might prefer msys2 over mingw and use gcc -c to compile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MinGW comes with its own Win32 API headers and libraries.

So don't mix this with headers from Microsoft.

Simply using `#include <windows.h>` should be sufficient.
The MinGW GCC compiler will know where to find it.
For linking you will need to add the necessary `-l` flags, and for those too MinGW GCC will know where to look.